# Where is the Sqlite database saved for asp.net core MVC 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I create an asp.net core mvc 2.2 application with

```
options.UseSqlite("Data Source=test.db")
```

Important note: VS2017 must be launched with Administrative Privilege, otherwise database cannot be created. It is specific to Asp.net core 2.2, the previous one has no such a problem.

## Question

Where is the sqlite database saved? I have searched for but I got nothing.

Note: As a comparison, Asp.net core 2.1 saves the sqlite database in the project folder.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\IIS Express` by default.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846333/serilog-does-not-write-log-to-file-while-using-inprocess-hosting-model-in-asp-ne/53859202#53859202) if you want to know about why it’s there and even how to work around the problem.

Comment: If you look at the answer I linked in my previous comment, the recommended approach would be to add the `CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory();` line to the start of `Main` so that the db file just gets saved to the correct location in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Control where it is stored the easy way

```
var connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB").Replace("~", _env.ContentRootPath);
services.AddDbContext<RemoteHealingTechContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connString));
```

Grabbing _env in the constructor

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _env = env;
}
```

Then you can use a connection string that looks like this

```
"DataSource=~\\App_Data\\MyDB.db"
```